# Problem using Refresh Command in Crystal Reports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

```
Dim logoninfo As TableLogOnInfo
  Dim SaleInvPrint As New ReportDocument


        SaleInvPrint.Load(My.Settings.CrystalReportLocation & "\SalesInvoiceA5.rpt")

        For Each tbcurrent As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In SaleInvPrint.Database.Tables

            logoninfo = tbcurrent.LogOnInfo()

            logoninfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = LocalDataAccessCon.ConnectionString

            '  logoninfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "[server]"

            ' logoninfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "[user]"

            ' logoninfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = "[password]"

            tbcurrent.ApplyLogOnInfo(logoninfo)

        Next

        SaleInvPrint.Refresh()
        SaleInvPrint.PrintToPrinter(1, True, 0, 50)
```

While using the above code, I get the following errors on the last line:

> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.DataSourceException: 'Error in File SalesInvoiceA5 13744_2344_{741BCC9A-4E81-4C98-8E3C-B5ECC6DAA5FA}.rpt:
> Failed to load database information.'

> > COMException: Error in File SalesInvoiceA5 13744_2344_{741BCC9A-4E81-4C98-8E3C-B5ECC6DAA5FA}.rpt:
> > Failed to load database information.

Strangely, if I remove `SaleInvPrint.Refresh()` , the error does goes away but I get some **old copy** of the print and not the latest one in the database!

Khalid.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal rpt files can contain old data if the designer of the report elected to 'Save Data with Report'. So what you are seeing is that saved data. The Refresh() method discards that saved data.

Focus your attention on figuring out why your attempt to connect to the data source is failing.